# How to manipulate a Solidity struct with Solidity?

Tags: function, struct, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm writing a smart contract where I'm creating an object (struct) in one function, and then I want to alter the properties in a different function. One of the struct's properties is added in a mapping and that's how I track them, but even though I have created a function to get the properties of the struct from the mapping, I still cant quite figure out how to change them.

This is the struct

```
struct Component {

    uint compID;
    string compManufacturer;
    string compDetails;
    address owner;
    address[] pastOwners;
    bool transfer;
}
```

This is an example of a function where I try to change the values in the struct.

```
function transfer (address factory, uint id) public {

    address compad;
    address[] compowners;
    bool boolean;

    (,,, compad, compowners, boolean) = getComponent(id);

    require(component.transfer == true);

    component.owner = factory;
    pastOwners = pastOwners.push(factory);
}
```

The function `getComponent` returns everything that is in the struct and here I initialize some local variables to store the ones that I need. However, I'm not sure what I do afterwards works, because this way the local variables seem useless, and if I change the local variables the changes won't go through in the actual object. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a mapping such as:

```
mapping(uint => Component) public components;
```

You can manipulate like this:

```
components[id].compDetails = "comp details";
```